# Converting a list with dashes into numbers

Tags: python

I made a list from a CSV file. It looks like this:

```
['18', '29', '0'...'0', '-14', '9']
```

It had a text element in the beginning, which I popped. Now, Python doesn't work with the list elements as with proper numbers. Whenever I try to parse the elements into floats, for example, I get the error message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: -
```

My code looks like this:

```
list2=[[float(column) for column in row] for row in list1]
```

Or this:

```
list2 = [map(float, x) for x in list1]
```

Both versions produce the same result. If I try a different data type, I get messages like:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

Can anyone tell me how do I get Python to parse the dash into a number correctly?

Comment: `float('-14')` works fine here. The error must be somewhere else?

Comment: What exactly's the list? Because `float('-14')` gives `-14.0`. It seems the error you get is because you have a `-` on its own in the list... Are you sure `list1` contain other lists?

Comment: I'm not sure about the data type of the list, but the second version should work for strings, should it not?

Comment: Why are you treating it as row/column couples then?

Comment: The full list is too long to post here, but it's all numbers like the ones above.

Comment: Because I got it from a CSV file, was a bit confused there. The second version is correct, but still produces a Value Error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the list you're creating is 1D but when you try and parse it you're treating it as a 2D list which will try converting each character in each element to a float (hence it throws an error while trying to do `float('-')`). Try replacing the line with the following to fix the problem:

```
list2 = map(float, list1)
```

You should also try adding `print list1` before that line to confirm that the list has the structure you think it has.